# java - a more efficient way to draw tiles?

Tags: java

I have a specific tile object in my program. It consists of two images which can also be flipped. The first column of tiles (whether it's from the left or the right side it depends on the 'flip' boolean) has to be the 'bricks0' image, while all other should be 'bricks1'. So, this works just as I want it to and I'm just explaining this to make things clear about the code.

I have two of these objects in my program (one of them is flipped and the other isn't), which . So, the problem is that it ruins the performance of the game when more images need to be drawn. For example, if I lower the height of these objects, or render only one object, there is no lag.

So, how do I make this work more efficiently?

```
@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {

    if(destroyed)
        return;

    //Initialises the height and width of a tile
    int tW = 0, tH = 0;

    BufferedImage img = bricks0;

    if(!flip) {
        for(int i = 0; i < w; i += tW) {

            //Sets the image to 'bricks1' if it's not the first column, else, uses the initialised type of the image 'bricks0'
            if(i != 0)
                img = bricks1;

            for(int j = 0; j < h; j += tH) {

                //Calculates the remaining width and height yet to be drawn
                int W = Math.abs(w - i), H = Math.abs(h - j);

                /*Sets the width and height of the image;
                 * The width of 'bricks0' is 53, while for 'bricks1' it's 64;
                 * Height is 64
                 */
                tW = img.getWidth();
                tH = img.getHeight();

                /* Calculates the width and height of the subimage that is cropped from the original;
                 * This is done to prevent an image getting drawn out of the object's bounds
                 */
                if(W > tW)
                    W = tW;
                if(H > tH)
                    H = tH;

                //Crops and draws the image
                img = img.getSubimage(0, 0, W, H);
                g.drawImage(img, this.x + i, this.y + j, null);

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int i = w; i > 0; i -= tW) {

            //Sets the image to 'bricks1' if it's not the first column, else, uses the initialised type of the image 'bricks0'
            if(i != w)
                img = bricks1;

            for(int j = 0; j < h; j += tH) {

                //Calculates the remaining width and height yet to be drawn
                int W = i, H = Math.abs(h - j);

                /*Sets the width and height of the image;
                 * The width of 'bricks0' is 53, while for 'bricks1' it's 64;
                 * Height is 64
                 */
                tW = img.getWidth();
                tH = img.getHeight();

                /* Calculates the width and height of the subimage that is cropped from the original;
                 * This is done to prevent an image getting drawn out of the object's bounds
                 */
                int x = 0, y = 0;

                if(W > tW) {
                    W = tW;
                }
                else {
                    x = tW - W;
                }
                if(H > tH) {
                    H = tH;
                }

                //Crops and draws the image
                img = img.getSubimage(x, y, W, H);
                g.drawImage(img, this.x + i - tW, this.y + j, null);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently drawing 26 images for both objects. 1 column is the 'bricks0' image, while the second is the 'bricks1' for each one of them.

edit: Okay, I've reduced the probability of a tile getting cropped by getSubimage(), but it still lags a little in cases when it has to cropp it..

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]